# Losing data in received serial string

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial

So part of a larger project needs to receive a long hex character string from a serial port using a raspberry pi.  I thought I had it all working but then discovered it was losing a chunk of data in the middle of the string.

```
def BUTTON_Clicked(self, widget, data= None):

        ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ex_device", 115200, timeout=3)

        RECEIVEDfile = open("RECIEVED.txt", "r+", 0) #unbuffered


        #Commands sent out
        ser.write("*n\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        ser.flush()
        ser.write("*E")
        ser.write("\r")

        #Read back string rx'd
        RECEIVED= ser.read()


        RECEIVED= re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', RECEIVED) #remove non-alphanumeric characters (caused by noise maybe?)
        RECEIVEDfile.write(re.sub("(.{4})", "\\1\n", RECEIVED, 0, re.DOTALL)) #new line every 4 characters


        RECEIVEDfile.close              
        ser.write("*i\r")
        ser.close
```

This is the script used to retrieve the data, the baud rate and serial commands are set right and the script is run as "unbuffered" (-u) but yet the full string is not saved.  The string is approx 16384 characters long but only approx 9520 characters (it varies) are being saved (can't supply the string for analysis).  Anyone know what I'm missing?  Cheers for any help you can give me.

Comment: What are you losing at the 'remove not-alphanumeric characters' step? It might be worth using the same regex to count up the number of characters removed there, and see if it matches the missing data.

Comment: Is a timeout of 3 seconds long enough to get the data? Can you try it with timeout=None?

Comment: I removed the parsing altogether to see if it was the problem, but alas no success.

Comment: Also tried the time=None, same result

Comment: How much does the length of the returned output vary? Does the len of the data in RECEIVED vary or the size of the resulting file? Is the data received correct? *[So many questions!]*

Comment: Hmmm weird, when I do a "print len(RECEIVED)" it returns 1... Am I being silly?

Comment: And yes the file size (and hence the RX string) does seem to vary.  But the data sent to it is always a fixed length so something weird is happening..

Comment: What if you don't read() but read(16384) or even a larger chunk, while increasing the timeout to e.g. 10 secs or more? According to docs read() defaults to reading 1 byte, so setting timeout to None won't guarantee you get everything unless you either loop or read larger chunks.

Comment: AH! Micke I could kiss you! That did the trick, thanks very much :D

Comment: Probably not an issue here, but might be worth noting that if you specify `read(16384) bytes and that doesn't come through it will block until timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad my comment helped!

Set timeout to a low number, e.g. 1 second. Then try something like this. It tries to read a large chunk, but times out quickly and doesn't block for a long time. Whatever has been read is put into a list (rx_buf). Then loop forever, as long as you've got pending bytes to read. The real problem is to 'know' when not to expect any more data.

```
rx_buf = [ser.read(16384)] # Try reading a large chunk of data, blocking for timeout secs.
while True: # Loop to read remaining data, to end of receive buffer.
    pending = ser.inWaiting()
    if pending:
         rx_buf.append(ser.read(pending)) # Append read chunks to the list.
    else:
         break

rx_data = ''.join(rx_buf) # Join the chunks, to get a string of serial data.
```

The reason I'm putting the chunks in a list is that the join operation is much more efficient than '+=' on strings.

Comment: This also removes "the noise" I was experiencing, must have been artefacts caused by the buffer not being happy

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243752/serial-port-does-not-work-in-rewritten-python-code) you need to read the data from the in buffer in chunks (here single byte):

```
out = ''
# Let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer).
time.sleep(1)
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    out += ser.read(1)
```

I suspect what is happening in your case is that you're getting an entire 'buffers' full of data, which depending on the state of the buffer may vary.

Comment: You might be able to do `out += ser.read(ser.inWaiting())` to get it in bigger chunks? Can't currently test it.