# pySerial cuts off text in file

Tags: android, python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to print out the content of a file on my Android through the serial port and it just cut off half of it.

My code look like this:

```
ser = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=0)
ser.write(' cat /sdcard/dump.xml \r\n')
sleep(5)
while ser.inWaiting():
    print ser.readline()
ser.close()
```

Cat works without any problems inside my serial port terminal so must be some setting with the Serial class. Does it have some maxlimit? I have tried to play around a bit with it's variables but can't seem to find anything that work.

Comment: Why do you sleep(5)? If you only get the last part of the file, I'm guessing that's your problem. Especially without hardware flow control, the receive buffer will just overflow.

Comment: Because if I remove the sleep I don't get any output at all. So a small sleep is required, but nothing seems to change if I increase the sleep past that. And it's the first part of the file I get.

Comment: I've posted an answer. In addition, this thread might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306816/losing-data-in-received-serial-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble seems to be that `inWaiting()` is returning false, causing the reading to stop. That is, if you loop fast enough there won't be any data "in waiting" (because you've just read it and looped).

Also note that `readline()` with no timeout (=0) will block until it sees a newline, meaning you can get stuck in the loop.

Better to increase the timeout to e.g. one second and do a sizable read() appending to a string (or list). Quit reading when you've exhausted the buffer and do whatever you want with the result. That is, if there is no way of knowing when you've received everything.

```
ser = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=1) # NB! One second timeout here!
ser.flushInput() # Might be a good idea?
ser.flushOutput()
ser.write(' cat /sdcard/dump.xml \r\n')
sleep(5) # I really don't think you need to sleep here.

rx_buf = [ser.read(1024)] # Try reading a large chunk. It will read up to 1024 bytes, or timeout and continue.
while True: # Loop to read remaining data, to the end of the rx buffer.
    pending = ser.inWaiting()
    if pending:
        rx_buf.append(ser.read(pending)) # Read pending data, appending to the list.
        # You'll read pending number of bytes, or until the timeout.
    else:
        break

rx_data = ''.join(rx_buf) # Make a string of your buffered chunks.
```

Disclaimer: I haven't got a Python interpreter with serial port available, so this is off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks! Will update tomorrow after I tried your solution at work, hopefully I get a better result.

Comment: It worked after some tweaking! I removed the sleep and added an extra check so stop when we get to the last node. Thanks again