# Losing bytes with ser.read - Python

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, uart

I am trying to read data out of a Microcontroller, configuration:19200,8 data bits, even parity and 1 stop bit. The controller is transmitting data via rs485 and I am reading the data via rs485 to rs232 converter. The data is transmitted every 4ms to a write and requires a reflection every 4ms on the respective bytes as displayed in the code. I have written a similar code on a microcontroller and everything works fine but I need to implement the same on Python. While reading from python I notice a few bytes are lost while reading through ser.read(). I also have a logic analyzer converted to see what data I am missing. I tried multiple solutions available on similar posts but it hasn't worked for me as the solutions require me to increase my timeout.
e.g. [Losing data in received serial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306816/losing-data-in-received-serial-string)

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial()

ser.port='COM1'  # This is COM1, use 1 for COM2 etc
ser.baudrate=19200
ser.bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN
ser.stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.xonxoff=0
ser.rtscts=0
ser.timeout=0

while True:
    rxbuf = ser.read(1)
    print(rxbuf)
    if(rxbuf == b'\x05' or rxbuf == b'\x06' or rxbuf == b'\x15'):
        time.sleep(0.004)
        ser.write(b'\x05')
    elif (rxbuf == b'\x02' or rxbuf == b'\x01'):  
        rxbuf_len = ser.read(16)
        print(rxbuf_len)
```

output:
b'\x05\'
b'\x05\'
b'\x05\'
b'\x05\'
b'\xF5\'
b'\x28\'
b'\x76\'
b'\x02\'
b'\xf2\x97\x00\x00\x8er\x9a\xc0\x14\xff\xff|:F\x18\x00'

This is incorrect there is a 0x02 before 0xF5 that has not been read apart from many other bytes.

Comment: At first: that code can't produce that output. Also if you sleep 4ms and do additional steps every itereation will be longer than 4ms.

Comment: @KlausD. You mean ser.read() cannot effeciently read data in 4ms? My baud rate is 19200, so that means I can read atleast 2 bytes per ms. Is there quite a bit of overhead to ser.read()? Is there a quicker way of reading this?

Comment: No, that's not what i wrote.

Comment: @KlausD. Ok I understand, I missed adding the print from my code(the code is much larger, I have just simplified my issue here). I fixed that. I am not really worried about the 4ms accuracy(the 4ms is to prevent data clogging of the RX/TX line). I am fine with a little longer duration. The concern is the data, I need to receive all the data. Is there an efficient way to collect all the data? The solution on the link in my post works when I read a large chunk of data, but when I read 1 byte I lose a few 1 bytes.

Comment: Python serial are same C++ serial, `if ser.inWaiting() > 0 :` equal to `if(Serial.available())`. `while True` not equal `while got data`.Need reset byte position index every packets. **You can't send only data without header and end header(CRC,"\r\n",etc.)**

Comment: @dsgdfg I didn't really get what you are trying to suggest? I am not sending a frame. And I am receiving a header 0x02 which is visible on the logic analyzer.